# power function returning unexpected results

Tags: function, pascal

Since pascal does not have a power function(unlike other languages) I was asked to create a function power. What I have done is this:

```
function pow(x,n:integer):integer;
    begin
    pow:=1;
    if n = 0 then
        pow:=1
    else if n=1 then
        pow:=x
    else if n > 0 then
        pow:=x*pow(x,n-1)
    else
        pow:=-x*pow(x,abs(n)-1);
end;
```

Now in the main body I have a for loop to show the powers of 8 from 0 to 8:

```
for i:=0 to 8 do
    writeln('8^',i,'=',pow(8,i));
```

The problem is that i get the following
if i is equal to 5 i get a negative number and if i is greater than 5 i get 0 as result.

Comment: first you might want to rethink the powers for negative numbers (it's not `*` but `/` in this case) - then you probably run to you usual overflows with integers (which is a bit strange since 8^5 is only 32768) - what do you get in your pascal interpreter if you do 8*8*8*8*8?

Comment: Maybe your pascal has, what Pascal do you use? E.g. Delphi and FPC have one in Math, and Free Pascal also supports ** for exponentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8<sup>5</sup> is 2<sup>15</sup>, which hit's the `integer`'s size limit causing an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). To avoid this, you could use a `longint` instead.

Comment: (I assume you mean longINT)